# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/common/annotations/Beta.class

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

This error occurred while running my project, unable to run my application for the build.

I have clean the build and rebuild the project again results in same problem.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/common/annotations/Beta.class
```

I have shared my gradle file below. Kindly help me to find the changes to be done in gradle file to run my application.

**Gradle File**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile 'com.uber.sdk:rides-android:0.5.3'
    compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.1'

    compile project(':branchsdk')
    compile project(':squarecamera')

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'
    compile 'com.facebook.rebound:rebound:0.3.8'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.5.0'
    compile 'se.emilsjolander.stickylistheaders:library:2.1.0'
    compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0')
            {   exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
                exclude module: 'support-annotations'
            }
    compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'){
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }

    compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.2'
    compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.5.3'
    compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:assets:0.5.3'
    compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'

    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.2'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
    }

    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.10.2'
    compile 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.5.1'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.0'

    compile 'org.solovyev.android.views:linear-layout-manager:0.5@aar'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'

    compile ('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0')
            {
                exclude group: 'com.android.support'
            }
    compile ('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1')
            {
                exclude group: 'com.android.support'
            }

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2'

    compile project(':ucrop')
    compile project(':library')

    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'

    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Kindly help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting stung by the Google collections rename to guava and you probably have both on your classpath.

See [Using module replacement rules](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/customizing_dependency_resolution_behavior.html#sec:module_replacement)

Eg:

```
dependencies {
    modules {
        module("com.google.collections:google-collections") {
            replacedBy("com.google.guava:guava", "google-collections is now part of Guava")
        }
    }
}
```

Or another problem could be this

```
fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

The jars in this libs folder can't participate in dependency resolution because there's no meta-data (eg group/artifact/version) so it's possible that there are duplicates here too

See [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/include-local-javadoc-with-gradle/26074/2) to store local jars in a maven directory layout instead